# salesforce lightning auth an org from another org using user agent OAuth flow and store access token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, salesforce-lightning

1. I have connected app created in org 2 with OAuth enabled.
2. I'm using OAuth2.0 User agent workflow in org1 where I have lightning app.
3. Upon clicking a button (named auth target org) in lightning component page,
4. window.open(endpturl,'_self');
   var currLoc = window.location.href;
   **alert ('Curr Loc is:  ' + currLoc);** //prints the URL from where I clicked button (named auth target org). Expected this statement to be executed after step 7. Hence not able to capture the access token.
5. Redirects to salesforce authorization/login page.
6. enter user credential --> click allow access.
7. Redirects to as per connected app configured callback URL 
   https://business-momentum-162-dev-ed.cs2.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success#access_token=abc&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdream-innovation-4602-dev-ed.cs40.my.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D540000009LzUEAU%2F00554000000zjC5AAI&issued_at=1531980498349&signature=abc&scope=id+api&token_type=Bearer

**BUT i'm not able to capture the access token as step 4 executed before step 7. Hence not able to capture access token**. Please do let me know if there is way to get/capture access token.

```
    client side controller code (**using window object**):
    ({ AuthTargetOrg : function (component, event, helper) {

    var endpturl = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=abc123&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbusiness-momentum-162-dev-ed.lightning.force.com%2Fservices%2Foauth2%2Fsuccess';

    window.open(endpturl,'_self');
    var currLoc = window.location.href;
    alert ('Curr Loc is:  ' + currLoc); //  prints home page URL from where I clicked "auth target org" button, rather this statement expected to execute after step 7.
   )}
```

Regards,
PJS

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use Apex to handle the redirect of the Oauth dance.  I've been struggling with this one myself and the problem is that in a lightning component you can't makes API calls directly to salesforce endpoints, it will throw all kinds of errors.  I did however find this code example:

https://balkishankachawa.wordpress.com/tag/oauth-with-lightning/

Basically the solution is to use Apex and Lightning Out.  Use Apex to receive your redirect from the Salesforce auth which can in turn get the token and pass it back to your lightning component.